# stop UIimageview animation at last image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, xcode5

```
NSArray *imageNames = @[@"2_00000.png", @"2_00001.png", @"2_00002.png", @"2_00003.png",
                            @"2_00004.png", @"2_00005.png", @"2_00006.png", @"2_00007.png",
                            @"2_00008.png", @"2_00009.png", @"2_00010.png", @"2_00011.png",
                            @"2_00012.png", @"2_00013.png", @"2_00014.png", @"2_00015.png",
                            @"2_00016.png", @"2_00017.png", @"2_00018.png", @"2_00019.png",
                            @"2_00020.png", @"2_00021.png", @"2_00022.png", @"2_00023.png",
                            @"2_00024.png", @"2_00025.png", @"2_00026.png", @"2_00027.png",
                            @"2_00028.png", @"2_00029.png", @"2_00030.png", @"2_00031.png",
                            @"2_00032.png", @"2_00033.png", @"2_00034.png", @"2_00035.png",
                            @"2_00036.png", @"2_00037.png", @"2_00038.png", @"2_00039.png",
                            @"2_00040.png", @"2_00041.png", @"2_00042.png", @"2_00043.png",
                            @"2_00044.png", @"2_00045.png", @"2_00046.png", @"2_00047.png",
                            @"2_00048.png", @"2_00049.png", @"2_00050.png", @"2_00051.png",
                            @"2_00052.png", @"2_00053.png", @"2_00054.png", @"2_00055.png",
                            @"2_00056.png", @"2_00057.png", @"2_00058.png", @"2_00059.png",
                            @"2_00060.png", @"2_00061.png", @"2_00062.png", @"2_00063.png"];

NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 1; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
}

// Normal Animation
UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-6, 40, 200, 1034)];
animationImageView.animationImages = images;
animationImageView.animationDuration = 2;

animationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;




[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];



[animationImageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: hacky way: stop animations at time=imageCount*animationDuration

Answer (score 3):

If you know the `animationRepeatCount` before starting your animation

```
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1  //For 1 loop
animationImageView.image = animationImageView.animationImages.lastObject;
```

---

For stoping animation dynamically

```
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0  //infinite loop
```

When you need to stop the animation

```
[animationImageView stopAnimating];
animationImageView.image = animationImageView.animationImages.lastObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

first set the animationRepeatCount to 1 and after starting the animation create a block that fires after the animation duration in this block set the animationImageView image to the last image .

```
dispatch_time_t dispatchAfter = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, animationImageView.animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(dispatchAfter, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

       animationImageView.image = [images lastObject];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `transitionWithView:duration:options:animation:completion:` of `UIView` for animating your `UIImageView`.

```
- (void)animatePictureTransition:(NSMutableArray *)arrayImages{

    [UIView transitionWithView:imageViewButton 
                      duration:1.0 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight 
                    animations:^{

         UIImage *newImage = (UIImage *)arrayImages.firstObject;
         imageViewButton.image = newImage;

     } completion:^(BOOL finished){

         [arrayImages removeObjectAtIndex:0];
         if(arrayImages.count) {
             [self animatePicturesTransition:arrayImages];
         }
     }];
}
```

You could use this recursive, and call the method again inside the completion blog and pass through the remaining `UIImages` this way there shouldn't be a problem to stop at the last `UIImages`.

I would also recommend you, to load the `UIImages` dynamically from the resource folder in this way:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getImagesWithSuffix:(NSString *)start andEndSuffix:(NSString *)end{

    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@.png", start, i, end];
        if([self fileExistsInProject:fileName]){
            [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];

        } else {

            break;
        }
    }
    return imageArray;
}
```

Always writing all names of your `UIImages` takes a lot of time and can cause any problems. This way you just have to order your pictures so you can loop over.

To use this code, create a `category` of `NSMutableArray` and you can use it!

Comment: @m.eldehairy: Thank you, It kindda worked,  but the animation is not working its just displaying the last image. Is their any other image seq animation method which will stop and display the last image. 

Can you plz explain it step by step.  Thank you

Comment: repeating animations are always a little bit tricky. You cannot loop through them inside a for loop, you have to handle this inside the completion block because this is the only place where you know the animation has really stopped.

Answer (score 0):

problem is with this line..

```
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
```

by setting animationRepeatCount = 0 its set to infinite by default.
if u want it stop at last image you can go with

```
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1; // specify no of times u need to run your animation.
```