# Animating icon in UIButton on click

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a UIButton which up on pressed should animate its icon through a set of images and stop at the last.

What I have is the following:

```
    let loadingImages = (1...8).map { UIImage(named: "slice\($0)")! }
    let animatedImage = UIImage.animatedImage(with: loadingImages, duration: 1.5)
    sender.setImage(animatedImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

After setting the image I could set a timer which could set the image to the last image. But I think its not very exact and not very nice code.

Is there a better way to animate an icon from its initial state image 1 of 30 to the last image 30 of 30 where it stops?

EDIT: @the4kman suggested to close this as a duplicate of [stop UIimageview animation at last image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534518/stop-uiimageview-animation-at-last-image)

Its not! That question uses UIImageView, this question uses UIButton. That question is for Objective-C, this question is for Swift 3. Does it resolve my question? No, the answer with currently one upvote is the same as I suggested myself with a timer. So no, this is a different question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stop UIimageview animation at last image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534518/stop-uiimageview-animation-at-last-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding UIImageView to the button is the simplest way I can think of. But still detecting animation finished is something you need to handle. I created a subclass of UIImageView that let you know when the animation is finished.

```
class AnimatedImageView: UIImageView, CAAnimationDelegate {

    var completion: ((_ completed: Bool) -> Void)?

    func startAnimate(completion: ((_ completed: Bool) -> Void)?) {
        self.completion = completion
        if let animationImages = animationImages {
            let cgImages = animationImages.map({ $0.cgImage as AnyObject })
            let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "contents")
            animation.values = cgImages
            animation.repeatCount = Float(self.animationRepeatCount)
            animation.duration = self.animationDuration
            animation.delegate = self

            self.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
        } else {
            self.completion?(false)
        }
    }

    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        completion?(flag)
    }
}
```

This is how to use
Set image view that will run the animation and add it to the button

```
var imageView: AnimatedImageView()

......

let loadingImages = (1...8).map { UIImage(named: "slice\($0)")! }
imageView.frame = button.bounds
imageView.image = loadingImages.first
imageView.animationImages = loadingImages
imageView.animationDuration = 1.5
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
yourButton.addSubview(imageView)
```

When button is clicked

```
imageView.startAnimate { (completed) in
    imageView.image = images.last
}
```